# Handler to popup window after refresh parent window

Tags: javascript, window, handler, popupwindow

I've a project in Java, with Java Script to manage site. I had a function to open help dialog popup window. When I refresh main page, a popup window don't close and it's still open. I have a protection, that you can open 2 windows with help, but it's working with handler (helpWnd), at it's loosing when refresh main page.

Sorry for my English; )

```
var helpWnd = null;
// Open help dialog with url from recived helpId
function openHelpDialog(helpId, height, width, title) {
    var url;
    if(helpId == "contact") {
        url = "help/contact.html";
    } else {
        var regularExpression = /[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/;
        if(helpWnd!=null) {
            helpWnd.close();
        }
        url = "help/index.html?"+helpId.toLowerCase()+".html";
        if(!regularExpression.test(helpId)) {
            url = "help/index.html";
        }
    }
    helpWnd = window.open(url, title, 'width=1000, height=600, menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=no');
}

//this refresh main page
function changeRole(roleName,redirectUrl) {
    dojo.xhrPost({
        content: {
            role: roleName 
        },
        handleAs: "json",
        sync: true,
        url: 'someUrl.npi',
        load: function (response) {
            dojo.cookie(response.cookieHash, response.role, {expires : response.cookieExpiryTime});
            document.location.href = redirectUrl;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening windows is considered harmful in many occations, as you might have found out yourself.

A better alternative is using modal dialogs with javascript, which is essentially a layered dialog in the same page. I'm not a Dojo expert but I quickly found documentations with Google (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html)

Anyway, if you still want to go for opening windows you might get better behaviour if you make sure it gets focused. Take a look here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html